# Finding which Debian distro CDs contain a certain package

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, software-installation

I am currently installing Debian Linux on a computer that does not have Internet access. I have burned the first few CDs from the distro and have a working system so far. However, I am unable to find some of the packages I want to install. How do I determine which CDs contain specific packages (and their dependencies), such as Emacs and haskell-platform?

**Clarification:**

I don't want to download all 50+ ISO images just to find one or two packages. How do I determine which ISO(s) contains the packages I want and their dependencies? For example, I downloaded the first 5 ISOs. However, I can't find the main Emacs package listed in Synaptic. How do I determine which ISO I need to download for the Emacs package and its dependencies?

Comment: If you have the CDs listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` then apt should tell you which CD is necessary to install the software you request to be installed.

Comment: @Marco I apologize that my question wasn't entirely clear. I have edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#search-for-package) FAQ entry.  Basically go to [this](http://cdimage-search.debian.org/) site and search for it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't find that with a google search; I probably didn't enter the correct search terms.